# Subscribe multiple threads to the same event signal to wake up

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a queue wrapper class which is storing items to a list, and multiple threads in the main program that are consuming these items until the list is empty. In this moment, the threads have to wait until the buffer will enqueue more items to the list.

I have an event fired every time that an item is enqueued, and I need to notify the threads that they have fresh items ready to consume.

```
 public event EventHandler ItemEnqueued;

    public void Enqueue(string item)
    {
        _itemsList.Add(item);            
        OnItemEnqueued();
    }
    

    void OnItemEnqueued()
    {
        ItemEnqueued?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

How can I notify the threads of the main program that an item has been enqueued?

Many thanks!

**EDIT to clarify**

```
    public class Queue 
{
    private readonly List<string> _itemsList = new List<string>();

    public void Enqueue(String val)
    {
        _itemsList.Add(val);            
        OnItemEnqueued();
    }
    

    void OnItemEnqueued()
    {
        //here I have to tell the threads that a new item has been added
    }

    public string Dequeue()
    {
            //FIFO queue
            if (_itemsList.Any())
            {
                var first = _itemsList.First();
                _itemsList.RemoveAt(0);

                return first;
            }
            
            return default(string);
       
    }

    public int Count()
    {
        return _itemsList.Count;
    }
}
```

}

And I have to create two threads and make them "fight" for the enqueued items:

```
    class Program
{
    readonly object _syncLock = new object();
    Queue _q = new Queue();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.InitThreads();
        
    }

    public void InitThreads()
    {
        lock (_syncLock) //exclusively add items 
        {
            for (var i = 0; i <= 99; i++)
            {
                _q.Enqueue(i.ToString());
            }
        }

        Thread t1 = new Thread(() => {
            while(_q.Count() > 0)
                Console.WriteLine("T1 dequeued " + Consume());

        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (_q.Count() > 0)
                Console.WriteLine("T2 dequeued " + Consume());              
        });
        

        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();

        //at some moment I have to tell the threads to wait until a new item has been enqueued
    }

    public string Consume()
    {
        lock (_syncLock) //safely get one item
        {
            return _q.Dequeue(); 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It sounds like you might be better off using a [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=net-5.0) and let your threads iterate using [`GetConsumingEnumerable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.getconsumingenumerable?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Or even Channels, DataFlow, Rx, or many other things as well. In short this has been solved lots of times, you might save your self some time and find a better solution out of the box

Comment: The point is that I have to solve it in this specific way, it is the exercise statement... Otherwise ofc I would have looked for another solution.

Comment: Then the solution will be more complicated than just signalling to the threads that a new item has been added - you will also need to ensure that only one thread at once is trying to dequeue items. However, you could use a `ManualResetEvent` or an `AutoResetEvent` to signal that an item has been added (depending on whether you want all threads or just one thread to proceed). Then your threads wait on the events being signalled before doing anything. There's more scaffolding that would be required, but your question is a bit too vague to post a definitive answer...

Comment: I tried to use ManualResetEvent or AutoResetEvent but I didn't know how, I have read a lot of pages and tutorials unsuccessfully. In the main program, I do lock the instance to let only one thread consume from the queue. But once it finishes, I don't know how to say to the different threads: hey, new items available, fight to get them.

I can see from the main program job.OnItemEnqueued but I don't know how to link it to the threads to make them wake up.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but here's a compliable code sample that demonstrates how to use `AutoResetEvent` to signal just one thread at once:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var signal = new AutoResetEvent(initialState:false);

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
                Task.Run(() => worker(signal));

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to wake a thread.");
                Console.ReadLine();
                signal.Set();
            }
        }

        static void worker(AutoResetEvent signal)
        {
            int threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Thread {threadId} is waiting for a signal.");
                signal.WaitOne();
                Console.WriteLine($"Thread {threadId} received a signal");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The key thing to note is that you create a single `AutoResetEvent` and pass it to all the threads, which then wait on it. Then the "main" thread signals the event when it wants one of the threads to respond.

I wouldn't use a `ManualResetEvent` for this kind of thing, because then all the threads would be signalled simultaneously, which it looks like you want to avoid.

Comment: Not exactly, I want the autoresetevent being fired from the queue class event (OnItemEnqueued). Many thanks

Comment: Well then you just call `signal.Set()` from `OnItemEnqueued()`

Comment: I'm so sorry man, I'm making lose your time bcs I'm not explaining well myself. I feel bad for that. I will fully rewrite and post all the code and it will be maybe easier to understand what I have to do.